# Showing there is a symplectomorphism of $(T^{*} M, \omega_{T^{*}M})$ satisfying this property

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry

**Problem:** Let $M$ be a manifold, and let $\alpha$ be a closed $1$-form on $M$. Show that there exists a symplectomorphism of $(T^{*} M, \omega_{T^{*} M})$ that maps the zero section to the submanifold $\text{Im}(\alpha) := \left\{ \alpha_x: x \in M \right\} $ of $T^{*} M$.

**Attempt:** The zero section of $T^{*} M$ is $$M_{0} = \left\{ (x, \xi) \in T^{*} M \mid \xi = 0 \ \text{in} \ T_x^{*} M \right\}. $$

My idea was to define the symplectomorphism $\phi$ as $\phi := \alpha \circ \pi$, where $\pi : T^{*} M \rightarrow M$ is the projection.

I have to show that $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism and that $\phi^{*} (\omega_{T^{*} M}) = \omega_{T^{*} M}$ ? However, this is where I am stuck. Also, I'm not sure where I need the closedness of $\alpha$.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\phi$ you defined isn't even a bijective map, since it maps the entire fibre $T_x^*M$ to $\alpha_x$. The appropriate $\phi$ is $\phi = \mathrm{id}_{T^*M}+\alpha\circ\pi$. Then if $\Theta$ is the canonical 1-form on $T^*M$ (defined by $\Theta_{\beta_x}(V_{\beta_x}) := \beta_x(T_{\beta_x}\pi\,(V_{\beta_x}))$ for $V_{\beta_x}\in T_{\beta_x}(T^*M)$), then
$$
(\phi^*\Theta)_{\beta_x}(V_{\beta_x}) = \Theta_{\phi(\beta_x)}(T_{\beta_x}\phi\,(V_{\beta_x})) = \phi(\beta_x)(T_{\phi(\beta_x)}\pi\,(T_{\beta_x}\phi\,(V_{\beta_x}))) \\= (\beta_x+\alpha_x)(T_{\beta_x}(\pi\circ\phi)(V_{\beta_x})) = (\beta_x+\alpha_x)(T_{\beta_x}\pi\,(V_{\beta_x}))=(\Theta+\pi^*\alpha)_{\beta_x}(V_{\beta_x}),
$$
i.e. $\phi^*\Theta = \Theta+\pi^*\alpha$. Hence 
$$
\phi^*\omega_{T^*M} = \phi^*(-d\Theta) = -d(\phi^*\Theta) = -d(\Theta+\pi^*\alpha) = \omega_{T^*M}-\pi^*(d\alpha).
$$
If $\alpha$ is closed, then $\phi$ is a symplectomorphism.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand a line you write. Why is $(\beta_x + \alpha_x) (T_{\beta_x} (\pi \circ \phi) (V_{\beta_x}) = (\beta_x + \alpha_x) (T_{\beta_x} \pi (V_{\beta_x})$? The $\phi$ has no effect in the differential?

Comment: Also, how do you know the zero section is mapped to that submanifold?

Comment: To answer your second question, $\phi = \mathrm{id}_{T^*M}+\alpha\circ\pi$ means $\phi(\beta_x) = \beta_x+\alpha_x$. So in particular, $\phi(0_x) = 0_x+\alpha_x = \alpha_x$, which is in the submanifold. To answer your first, $\phi$ maps the fibre $T_x^*M$ into itself, implying that $\pi\circ\phi = \pi$.

Comment: Sorry I still do not understand why $\pi \circ \phi = \pi$. Can you prove this with a calculation? If $p = (x, \xi_x) \in T^{*} M$, I have $\pi(\phi(p)) = \pi( (x, \xi_x) + \alpha_x)$? Maybe I am confused

Comment: $\pi$ maps every 1-form to its base point, so when restricted to the fibre $T_x^*M$ of $T^*M$ (the space of 1-forms at the point $x\in M$), it maps everything to $x\in M$. $\phi$ just adds $\alpha_x$ to any 1-form $\beta_x$, and so $\pi(\phi(\beta_x)) = \pi(\beta_x+\alpha_x) = x = \pi(\beta_x)$, implying that $\pi\circ\phi = \pi$. Your notation of writing an element $p\in T^*M$ as $(x,\xi_x)$ is a bit redundant (since the $x$ already appears in $\xi_x$), but if you want to do this, you should also write $\alpha_x$ as $(x,\alpha_x)$.